# Idangerous Swiper for ul/li not working

Tags: jquery, html-lists, swiper.js

I have an ul-list with 3 li elements and want to swipe them in a cube but its not working, maybe Im wrong with the swiper wrapper or swiper slide classes?

```
    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    effect: 'cube',
    grabCursor: true,
    cube: {
        shadow: true,
        slideShadows: true,
        shadowOffset: 20,
        shadowScale: 0.94
    }
});
</script>



<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                 <li>hello world</li>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                 <li>hello world</li>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                 <li>hello world</li>
            </div>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you initialize the swiper in the body or after document ready?

Comment: After document ready.